# How to avoid null properties in @ModelAttribute in java spring?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, modelattribute

I have a controller method that will update database records based on values I get as parameter in that controller. I am taking a class as parameter that has more than 50 properties along with getter setter methods using `@ModelAttribute`, now the problem i am facing is that I may get many null values or say, I may not get certain properties as parameter, then how to ignore such properties in modelattribute and update only those fields whose values I got from form.

Example:

My class is as follows:

```
public class PersonalDetails implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long personalDetailsId;

    @Column(name = "P_Name")
    private String personName;

    @Column(name = "P_Surname")
    private String surname;

//getter setters below
}
```

In controller, i am taking parameter as follows:

```
@ModelAttribute PersonalDetails details
```

Now **problem occurs when I DONT get `personName` parameter from form submission or any other member of this class. How can I avoid certain fields if those are passed null while hitting my controller method?**

**Is it possible for @ModelAttribute to update only those fields in my database whose values are received and ignore those that are null?**

Comment: `@ModelAttribute` does nothing for update fields in database. It is needed just for add object into model.

Comment: @KenBekov is right. You might find some annotation in Spring JPA, put into `PersonalDetails`, that only update columns if they are not null. But AFAIK, there is NOT any annotation in JPA like that